npm ERR! C40E0000:error:1C800066:Provider routines:ossl_gcm_stream_update:cipher operation failed
When trying to install NextJS latest version by this code
npx create-next-app@latest

I am facing the following error:
An error occurred
npm ERR! code ERR_SSL_CIPHER_OPERATION_FAILED
npm ERR! C40E0000:error:1C600055:Provider routines:ossl_gcm_stream_update:cipher operation failed:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\providers\implementations\ciphers\ciphercommon_gcm.c:327:npm ERR!

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\robert\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-12-27T18_34_58_323Z-debug-0.log 

Installing new 'openssl' is not solved the problem
